# Create a new variable ignoring NA

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset with multiple variables that represent patients, lab IDs and results. It looks something like this:

```
     id    lab.1   result.1  lab.2   result.2   lab.3   result.3   lab.4    result.4
1    110   2039    0         2039    0          NA      NA         NA       NA
2    203   1778    5694      1778    908        1778    786        NA       NA
3    218   13490   579       13490   276        1067    243        13490    152
4    222   495     0         495     495        0       495        495      0
5    231   1067    966117    306    82794       NA      NA         NA       NA
6    238   2821    89        2821    NA         NA      NA         NA       NA
```

The problem is that I need to create a new variable that indicates if the lab is the same in all 'lab' variables (0/1). The result that I'm expecting is like this:

```
   samelab
1  1
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0
6  1
```

However, many variables are NAs and I can't figure out how to solve it since I can't recode NAs because it means something.

I tried to use  `df$samelab = ifelse(df$lab.1 == df$lab.2 & df$lab.3 & df$lab.4, 1, 0)` but it generates NA results.

I would really appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: In the 4th row, you have 0 as value.  Do you  consider that as different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to subset the columns that starts with 'lab' (or use `startsWith`).  Then, we compare with the first column and get the `rowSums` of the logical matrix, check if the count is equal to the number of columns, change the logical vector to binary with `+`

```
df1 <- df[grep('lab', names(df))]
n1 <- rowSums(df1== df1[,1], na.rm = TRUE)
n2 <- rowSums(!is.na(df1) & df1 != 0)
df$samelab <- +(n1 == n2)
```

---

Another option is to check the `length` of `unique` elements

```
+(apply(df1, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))) == 1)
```

If we dont' consider `0`

```
df$samelab <- +(apply(df1, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x) & x != 0]))) == 1)
df$samelab
#[1] 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

---

Or an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(samelab =  as.integer(n_distinct(setdiff(na.omit(c_across(
          starts_with('lab'))),
           0)) == 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
# Rowwise: 
#     id lab.1 result.1 lab.2 result.2 lab.3 result.3 lab.4 result.4 samelab
#  <int> <int>    <int> <int>    <int> <int>    <int> <int>    <int>   <int>
#1   110  2039        0  2039        0    NA       NA    NA       NA       1
#2   203  1778     5694  1778      908  1778      786    NA       NA       1
#3   218 13490      579 13490      276  1067      243 13490      152       0
#4   222   495        0   495      495     0      495   495        0       1
#5   231  1067   966117   306    82794    NA       NA    NA       NA       0
#6   238  2821       89  2821       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA       1
```

Comment: thank you!! The second option worked perfectly! @akrun

Comment: @AngélicaSantos the first option I posted before I checked the NA issue.  The second and third should work for that case